# Finding all unique relationship paths in a mapping table using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
            id_a                                 id_b
  (1) jkshdgvksjhsjk8983298jhsdhj          llkmlkmsdgsdf97897998
  (2)  llkmlkmsdgsdf97897998             sdkjvhkasdk3298798kjdjsk               
  (3) jkshdgvksjhsjk8983298jhsdhj      yiuyweruiyriueshjdbvjh89238
  (4) cxmnvbmnxmbnxcv4398744jskdhk         bxcmnvbnmxcweuiy84398
```

In my dataset, there are no keys except for the combinations of the attributes (i.e. row 1 indicates a relationship between id_a and id_b in that row, ditto for row 2, etc.). Also, the data is hierarchical -- in row 1, id_a is related to id_b. In row 2, the id_b from row 1 is now id_a and is related to the id_b in row 2 (i.e. there is now a hierarchical relationship: **jkshdgvksjhsjk8983298jhsdhj**  --> **llkmlkmsdgsdf97897998** --> **sdkjvhkasdk3298798kjdjsk**).

There is also a relationship between **llkmlkmsdgsdf97897998** (the id_b from row 1 and the id_a from rows 2 and 3) and another id (**yiuyweruiyriueshjdbvjh89238**) such that **llkmlkmsdgsdf97897998** is now part of the following relationship path:

(1) **jkshdgvksjhsjk8983298jhsdhj**  --> **llkmlkmsdgsdf97897998** --> **sdkjvhkasdk3298798kjdjsk**

The first element of that path (**jkshdgvksjhsjk8983298jhsdhj**) is part of another path: **jkshdgvksjhsjk8983298jhsdhj** --> **yiuyweruiyriueshjdbvjh89238**.

In my output, I would like to show both of these paths *as well as* the path represented by the relationship in row 4 (**cxmnvbmnxmbnxcv4398744jskdhk**  --> **bxcmnvbnmxcweuiy84398**) but I do NOT want to show the intermediary relationship path (**llkmlkmsdgsdf97897998** --> **sdkjvhkasdk3298798kjdjsk**) because it would be redundant.

What is the best way to generate a list of these unique paths such that all hierarchical relationships are captured (regardless of the number of levels in the hierarchy -- my data might have 50+ levels) *and* subsidiary/lower-level relationships are not? Thanks, and please let me know if I can clarify.

Comment: you may want to rephrase the question with shorter values (e.g. A, B, C etc.) in the ID fields along with the desired output - just helps to understand the requirement better

Answer (score 0):

This should be:

```
select connect_by_root(id_a) root, id_b
  from your_table
  where connect_by_isleaf = 1
  start with not exists (select 1 from your_table x where id_b = your_table.id_a)
  connect by prior id_b = id_a
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=98255842c0eff63cae687264c940d21c)</sup>**

`connect_by_root` shows first ID in hierarchy. `connect_by_isleaf = 1` hides all intermediary rows. `start_with` causes query to start only from roots.